# Is anyone using Half-Bit encryption? What is it used for now?

Tags: encryption, symmetric

Long ago I learned about an encryption scheme which uses a random mask of bits which were "half on". I don't recall all the details, but basically, if a mask bit was a one, the input bit was passed through, if not the output bit was random. So, the decryption would lose information (it was nondeterministic) but for something like an image, which could still be recognized if degraded (or text read from a noisy image), it was "good enough".

Is this being used for anything these days? Does this technique have good qualities that other encryption methods do not? I was able to find only one paper online by searching on "half-bit encryption" and I am not certain it describes the method I am remembering. Perhaps I am using the wrong name?

One potential application is for monochrome images. For example, I store an image of myself passed through this filter: it looks like noise. I can use the mask to reveal a picture of myself to someone, but no one else can. Or, I carry the output file with me, and only someone with the mask can reveal the photo and see that it is me: a form of identification. It would have to be read by eye, of course, so this is not a way to send files across the internet or something. But not everything that can be digitized is digits, so to speak. ("*Not everything that counts can be counted, and not everything that can be counted counts.*" - Einstein)

Comment: If this is all, this is no encryption. It just destroys data without any benefit.

Comment: So what happens when bits are lost in transit? Looks like it wouldn't self-synchronize, at this point why not just use proper encryption together with proper error correction rather than a defective hybrid of the two?

Comment: Bits are not "lost" in the sense that the file gets shorter. Their values are just randomized. The mask looks like noise. The output stream looks like noise. You need the mask to recover an encoded stream. I think the idea was that a long time ago, before powerful computers and algorithms, a message could be sufficiently obscured that no one could recover it without the mask, and even with the proper recovery method it was not a bitwise copy of the original but instead something that had to be printed and read by eye. So it did not yield to any automatic decryption, like "Navaho code talk".

Comment: @deviantfan The *benefit* is that the data cannot be automatically recovered, but can still be used, for example by looking at the noisy image. My driver's license has a small, noisy copy of my photo in the corner for some reason. I have no idea why. Hmm...

Comment: @nocomprende Let me rephrase that: At least without doing anything encryption-like. ... About your driving license, I don't know where you are, but with name etc. and possibly a "good" picture on it too, there still is little/no benefit.

Comment: I very much doubt that I have well understood your OP, but from your sentence "I can use the mask to reveal ..."  I suppose it could be profitable for you to at least  take a look of visual cryptography and see whether it could eventually somehow satisfy your needs.

Comment: I suppose that I am imagining "non-digital" ways of dealing with information, and a wider scope of the concept than just "bits in a file". After all, we deal with non-digital information all the time: sense data, spoken words, remembering the route to a place... The world is not really digital, and there are many many ways of dealing usefully with it that cannot be captured in a strictly digitized representation. Thinking that everything must be able to reduce to bits is a damaging kind of hubris. Please keep minds open!

Comment: What would Siri do with a noisy distant AM radio broadcast? Would handwriting recognition software work with crummy writing passed through  a very coarse halftone screen? My ears and eyes can deal with those easily. I would be annoyed, but the information would be fully recoverable. This is what I am talking about. Sometimes Analog has advantages.

Comment: If this is what you are talking about, then it has absolutely nothing to do with crypto :/ what you're looking for is more related to machine learning, AI and the kind. You basically want something that's close to captcha: some puzzle hard to solve for a machine (here, a noisy music), but easy for a human.

On a side note, I think it would be extremely easy for a machine to recover the file from a noisy file - like, finding the correct music in a database from the music masked with your method. Way easier than for a human.

Comment: @GeoffroyCouteau right, I am, in a way, asking about techniques which are useful but that "hide" the desired information from automated search and recovery. This is similar to how we want to be able to identify people and / or authenticate who they are, without it being something that could be spoofed or bypassed with an exhaustive search. **Until that happens, I think that computers are going to be more of a liability than a help.** There must be a boundary between the tool and the user, and the user must have the final say (*"dammit!"*) or else we will not have safe and trustworthy systems.